# How can i see if my flickering light is working right without rendering the animation?

Tags: light, fcurves

I have a flickering light using f-curves. Is there any way to judge the strength of the flickering without rendering the animation over and over?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into to texture display? It shows a crude representation of light intensity and placement. Eevee is another option that would allow you to visualise your lights easier.

Comment: i have tried texture display but it doesnt seem to show any light on my floor plane?

Comment: That sounds like you have a technical issue somewhere. Without any pictures or your file scene, it's a bit hard to diagnose. Also if your light is too big, it might be impossible to differentiate between lit and shadow.

Comment: ok i will do some tests and try and get some screen shots if needed.